# Unexpected behaviour with AWS Lambda

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

**What I've done**

I've created a project using Serverless cli, from `aws-kotlin-jvm-maven` template. After that I've edited my serverless.yml template this way:

```
service: test
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8
  region: eu-west-1
package:
  artifact: target/test-1.0.0.jar
functions:
  hello:
    handler: com.example.Handler
    events:
      - schedule: rate(2 minutes)
```

And I've edited my Handler this way:

```
class Handler:RequestHandler<Map<String, Any>, ApiGatewayResponse> {
    override fun handleRequest(input:Map<String, Any>, context:Context):ApiGatewayResponse {
        BasicConfigurator.configure()
        LOG.info("Hello, World!")
        return ApiGatewayResponse()
    }
    companion object {
        private val LOG = Logger.getLogger(Handler::class.java)
    }
}
```

I was expecting my Lambda to run every 2 minutes, logging a "Hello, World!" on CloudWatch, every 2 minutes.

**My problem**

What I found on cloudWatch logs is the following:

1st run: 
"Hello, World!"

2nd run: 
"Hello, World!"
"Hello, World!"

3rd run: 
"Hello, World!"
"Hello, World!"
"Hello, World!"

...and so on.

Any suggestion on what's happening here?

Comment: Does the problem persist over long periods of time (>15-30min) or does it repeat itself eradically? This could be a clue as to this being linked to the same container-instance. It might be a problem, where the container instance is still running with a combination of some form of caching that results in this behavior.

Comment: After 2 hours execution is still incrementing the number of "hello world"... I thought about that too, but can't explain why since lambda should be stateless...

Comment: Ok @DrEigelb , this issued is linked with the container-instance lifetime. When it's re-created, it will start from the beginning. Any hint about this?

Comment: Just as I thought, @abierto. I dont't know very much Kotlin, but I suspect there might be some funky stuff going on in the companion object where you call the `getlogger`. Try instantiating the logger (and the logging logic) outside the `Handler` class if you want to use your logger. There is also some tips from AWS on logging in Java, which might help (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the logging dependency to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.symphonia</groupId>
    <artifactId>lambda-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I've found a very useful article here: https://blog.symphonia.io/a-love-letter-to-lambda-logging-974b0eb49273